# Using table keys with periods in Lua

Tags: lua, key, lua-table

In Lua, assigning a table with a specified key might go like this:

```
a = { x = 4 }
```

...or perhaps like...

```
a = { ['x'] = 4 }
```

Easy enough. However, if I introduce periods into the key (as in a domain name) nothing seems to work.  All of the following fail:

```
a = { "a.b.c" = 4 }
a = { a.b.c = 4 }
a = { ['a.b.c'] = 4 }
a = { ["a.b.c"] = 4 }
a = { [a.b.c] = 4 }
```

All of these return the same error:

```
$ ./script.lua
/usr/bin/lua: ./script.lua:49: `}' expected near `='
```

What am I missing here? Several of the examples seem quite straight-forward and should work (while others have apparent problems).

Comment: At least two of your examples should work in Lua. ({ ['a.b.c'] = 4 }
 and { ["a.b.c"] = 4 } ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In lua table element may be either a Name or an Expression. Citing language reference, "Names (also called identifiers) in Lua can be any string of letters, digits, and underscores, not beginning with a digit.", and everything else is interpreted as an identifier in this context. Therefore, `a.b.c` as a table index is treated as expression, which is evaluated to get the actual table index. This would work, but would be useless:

```
a = { b = { c = 1 } }
x = {}
x['a.b.c'] = 7

print(x['a.b.c'])
```

Also note, that `foo.a.b.c` is equal to `foo['a']['b']['c']` and not to `foo['a.b.c']`.

Comment: Another poster hit the problem on the head - _"Is something else wrong with your script?"_ - but this is the most complete answer. Somehow, in getting an example put together like above, something broke. The answers hinge on the fact that `["a.b.c.d"]` and `['a.b.c.d']` were string literals as table keys, and `[a.b.c.d]` is the value `a.b.c.d` as a table key.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = { ['a.b.c'] = 4 }
a = { ["a.b.c"] = 4 }
```

These two are all valid.

```
a = { [a.b.c] = 4 }
```

This *could* be valid, depending on the exact identifiers used. For example

```
b = { c = { d = "Ohai!" } } }
a = { [b.c.d] = 4 }
```

would be valid.

If your interpreter is telling you they are not valid, then you've either done something else wrong, or there's a bug in the interpreter. The others however would not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something else wrong in your script?

```
$ ./lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> a = { ["a.b.c"] = 4 }
> print (a["a.b.c"])
4
> print (a.a)
nil
```